# How to create a JButton Array with existing JButtons in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, jbutton, background-color

I'm doing a color pencil project using 100 JButtons as pixels positioned like a 10x10 matrix. I also have 10 other jButtons representing colors and 2 other representing the tools "pencil" and "bucket".

Im only working with the pencil jButton for now, so you can paint any of the 100 JButtons by clicking the pencil JButton and then picking one of the color JButtons.

The algorithm works fine, the problem is the fact I need to apply the same coloring method (colorButton) to all the 100 JButtons so i wanted to make an Array to store all the JButtons and then call my colorButton method for each of them.

I have no clue on how to store all my 100 JButtons into the JButton array, since they are already created and named.

This is what im trying:

```
public void colorButton(JButton button){
    if (type == "pencil"){
        if(color.equals("gray")){
            button.setBackground( new Color(101,101,101));
        }else if(color.equals("white")){
            button.setBackground( new Color(255,255,255));
        }else if(color.equals("black")){
            button.setBackground( new Color(0,0,0));
        }else if(color.equals("blue")){
            button.setBackground( new Color(0,0,255));
        }else if(color.equals("red")){
            button.setBackground( new Color(255,0,0));
 }

 public void buttonArray(){
    JButton[] button = new JButton[100];

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        button[i] = jButton1; //I need to get each of the 100 buttons here
        colorButton(button[i]);
    }
 }
```

So other than only JButton1 i need a way to store all of the 100.

Any idea?

Thanks

*Edited to clarify the question and situation

Comment: You just allocated an array contained 100 elements but not allocated each element. In other words, you need do this `button[i]=new JButton`. This is a simple question but could be easily ignored.

Comment: (off-topic): Don't do String comparisons with `==`.  You need to use `String.equals()`.

Comment: `"since they are already created and named."` -- ouch. Don't do this. Create the buttons in a for loop, and assign them to the JButton array or `ArrayList<JButton>` within the same loop. Don't use 100 variable names as that way leads to madness and a debugging nightmare.

Comment: @GeminiKeith Yup I'm aware I could do this with new JButtons, but I was wondering if I could do a similar thing with the jButtons i have already created, since I positioned them in a grid layout using the NetBeans GUI. Thanks though

Comment: @GregKopff Thanks for pointing that out. Im used to do comparisons using == instead of .equals() for Strings, this is a habit i have to change.

Comment: Then you can try clone method and only update necessary attributes.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Yeah it does work better, but I was looking for a way to store the already created buttons since I have their positions arranged in a JFrame using the NetBeans GUI and wanted to keep them properly positioned without having to manually .setLocation() each of them

Comment: @GeminiKeith Im not familiar with the clone method, but sounds like an interesting alternative, ill look it up and try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the context of what this is used for and assuming the *colorButton()* method is a mock as it is missing a couple of braces.

The following Java code uses reflection to populate an ArrayList using the existing JButtons defined in the *ColorButtons* class.

I am still unsure why you need to assign the Array in a loop with another List, but here it is.

```
public class ColorButtons {
    // JButton sample.
    private JButton button1 = new JButton("1");
    private JButton button2 = new JButton("2");
    private JButton button3 = new JButton("3");

    // This is used to store the buttons.
    ArrayList<JButton> jbuttons = new ArrayList<JButton>();

    // Boilerplate, as I have no idea what this does.
    private String type = "pencil";
    private String color = "white";

    /**
     * Populate the JButton List on instantiation.
     * 
     * @see ColorButtons#populateJButtonList()
     */
    public ColorButtons() {
        // Populate "jbuttons" ArrayList with JButtons.
        this.populateJButtonList();
    }

    public void colorButton(JButton button) {
        if (type == "pencil") {
            if (color == "gray") {
                button.setBackground(new Color(101, 101, 101));
            } else if (color == "white") {
                button.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
            } else if (color == "black") {
                button.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0));
            } else if (color == "blue") {
                button.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 255));
            } else if (color == "red") {
                button.setBackground(new Color(255, 0, 0));
            }
        }
    }

    public void buttonArray() {
        JButton[] button = new JButton[100];

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            // Assign each JButton in the list to array element.
            for (JButton jbutton : jbuttons) {
                button[i] = jbutton; // I need to get each of the 100 buttons
                                        // here
                System.out.println("Button" + button[i].getText());
                colorButton(button[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * This is used to add the JButtons to a list using reflection. Used in the
     * constructor.
     * 
     * @see ColorButtons#ColorButtons()
     */
    public void populateJButtonList() {
        // Gets the class attributes, e.g. JButton, String, Integer types, everything.
        // In this case it is this class, but can define any other class in your project.
        Field[] fields = ColorButtons.class.getDeclaredFields();

        // Loop over each field to determine if it is a JButton.
        for (Field field : fields) {

            // If it is a JButton then add it to the list.
            if (field.getType().equals(JButton.class)) {
                try {
                    // De-reference the field from the object (ColorButtons) and cast it to a JButton and add it to the list.
                    jbuttons.add((JButton) field.get(this));
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException
                        | SecurityException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        ColorButtons color = new ColorButtons();

        color.buttonArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup I forgot to mention the part I used from my method is a mock, the remaining part of it is composed of more colors so i thought it wouldnt be necessary to copy the whole thing. Just to clarify a bit, the Strings color and type are global variable used to determine which Jbutton was clicked, as I have another set of 10 jButtons representing colors and 2 types of tools, Pencil and Bucket. The variables type and color would be assigned depending on what color and tool was chosen.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the use of reflection to populate the Array with the jButtons i have already created. I'm not familar with Reflection nor the Field object and I can't quite understand how the populateJButtonList method would work, so ill have to look it up to use it properly on my future codes. Ill give a try using the code you wrote up tho. Thanks for the help

Comment: I am revising with more comments to explain what the code involving reflection is doing.

Comment: Yeah I kind of figured out what the Reflection does, thanks for updating the comments. Ill find a way to apply your Class into the whole project with the already-created classes. Otherwise ill just start over creating new buttons inside a 10x10 Grid Layout jPanel. Thanks for the help guys